# expo authentication google working on emulator perfectly but not working on expo go app on phone and on standalone app

Tags: react-native, expo, google-authentication, expo-go

On standalone app it showing
`You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure` this and nothing happening. But in emulator everything is working fine.

my code

```
import * as GoogleSignIn  from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

    const [request, response, promptAsync] = GoogleSignIn .useAuthRequest({
       expoClientId: 'id',
       androidClientId: 'id', 
    });
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (response?.type === 'success') {
        const { authentication } = response;
        }
    }, [response]);
```

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same issue. Only tried on emulator currently, but not working on Android. Works fine on iOS

Comment: yes! pass this parameter into you promptAsync function like this "promptAsync({ useProxy: false, showInRecents: true })" and make sure u have generated the SH key as the doc said it will work on emulator when the useProxy params is passed true and when on build apk make sure thats remain false.